# Server side PHP code to communicate with Enfora Unit

Tags: php, sockets

Hope there is someone on here that can help me.

I bought a `Enfora MT4000` tracking unit to test and play with. Now, I was able to write the server side code to open a port, accept the connection from the unit, read and display it.

The problem now, is that I need to be able to connect from the server side to unit (using the unit's IP and Port it connected to the server with) and also be able to send it's Commands and get a response.

For example, if I send the command `ATI` to the unit, I receive a response of `Enfora`. This works when I work through the [enfora test server](http://apitest.enfora.com/enforaapp/).

I have also tried with `socket_*`, `stream_socket_*`, and `fopen`/`fwrite` but nothing seems to work.

Could someone please shed some light for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `fopen`? Was there any error?

Comment: Hi feeela. No there was nothing wrong with fopen, all the above examples works to receive the data from the Unit but none of them can send any commands to the unit

Comment: This sounds like the executing process doesn't have the right s to do so. How do you run the PHP program/via which SAPI?

Comment: I run the PHP in Putty